# parse date with stringify | ANGULAR -> Spring Boot

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I tried to get date via owl-date-time and parse with stringify for filter.

I choose 8 April 2020.
I got something like this after stringify parsing - 2020-04-07T22:00:00.000Z
After sending request to spring boot I try to parse it to LocalDate, but i get 7.april instead of 8.april...
Exists way to parse it correctly in backend? In angular is stringify parsing solution as universal for each filter element.

Comment: Your stringified date is literally 7th of april...

Comment: `2020-04-07T22:00:00.000Z` - the date from the fronted is 7th of April.

Comment: I think that this is because your timezone is UTC+2. Internally, the date is right (8 april 2020 00:00:00), but when you print it (or stringify it) it will be displayed as '2020-04-07 22:00' (2 hours less). One possible (and quick) solution is to parse the date before sending it to the backend. Something like this: `let dateToSend = pickedDate.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0'+(pickedDate.getMonth()+1)).substr(-2) + '-' + ('0'+(pickedDate.getDate())).substr(-2);`. This will construct a string like "2020-04-08".

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with timezones.
Your original date is 8 april 2020, but stringify gave you `2020-04-07T22:00:00.000Z` probably because you have a 2 hours shift with UTC.
Now you try to convert this to a `LocalDate`, which does not take into account time zone, so all it see is the first part: `2020-04-07`, hence your result.

There are 2 ways to solve this:

- Build your js date with you own time zone, not UTC, or
- In your Java code, convert this UTC date to a date into your timezone (in java 8 you can use `ZonedDateTime`, with joda you can use `DateTime`). Then build a `LocalDate` from this date if you need it.